# No specs found issue in protractor with success run

Tags: node.js, protractor, automated-tests

I am running my protractor tests in PhpStorm 8.0.1. The issue is despite of providing the parameter correctly in Application parameters section, the script does not run, and even then it outputs a success run in the console. Here is the output.

```
[12:45:30] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[12:45:30] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
1..0 # All tests disabled
# 0 specs, 0 failures, 0 skipped, 0 disabled in 0.014s.
# NOTE: disabled specs are usually a result of xdescribe.
SUCCESS: 0 specs, 0 failures, 0 skipped, 0 disabled in 0.015s.


No specs found
Finished in 0.016 seconds
[12:45:34] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:45:34] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My application parameter is configured like this.

http://screencast.com/t/HOqAW6ya4oe

And here is my folder structure which accordingly is correctly configured.

http://screencast.com/t/xK98JrDlc2a

This was working earlier fine and now all of a sudden I get this output. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be of great help.

Comment: By looking at your error stacktrace. All your tests have been disabled by putting `xdescribe`. Just change it to `describe` and it should work!

Comment: I cannot see where I have disabled my specs using xdescribe. Seems peculiar. Here is the spec snapshot.
http://screencast.com/t/ggV3hJBm

Comment: can you paste your `config.js`?

Comment: Here is the download link
 http://content.screencast.com/users/bishwaroopc/folders/Default/media/7524c65a-c5df-4c61-a8ab-7d497ffbd09e/nwp_conf.js?downloadOnly=true

Comment: What is your project directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

`specs: [ '../specs/WP-lam_spec.js' ],` I think it is a couse change it to  :

`specs: ['spec/**/*[sS]pec.js'],`

so it will start all your specs you got in your spec folder, also i think it might be problem with lack of '' in parameter from screenshot so just change to:

`protractor --specs='path\to\file.spec.js'`

Answer (score 0):

My  spec.js file was in src.com.sam.scriptjs package so giving like below in config.js was  solved my issue .

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/firstScript.js']

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tests are in the same folder as the config file, you can try to add ./ before your spec:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./helloWorld.js']
  }
```